# How to sort the results by a relation Dynamic Laravel and Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I know that to order the elements of a relation, we use with and pass a function to tell Eloquent to order by a specific column of the relation

```
$query->with(['relation' => function ($query) { 
    $query->orderBy('columName', 'ASC');
}]);
```

I try to sort and filter dynamically for relationships between tables, since I sent the relation.fieldrelation format to order or to search, as I do to do this from eloquent or QueryBuilder, so that it works dynamically and for any model and any relationship?

This method I have in a trait so that it can work for any model and for any relationship, but it does not order and search correctly, that is, to sort and search the records of the base model by the field of its relation `where('relation.campo','like','$data');`  and  `oderBy('relacion.campo','ASC');` How can it be done using Eloquent or would I have to use queryBuilder if or what?

From the controller I call well

```
return Model::with('relation')->GetDataTable($request);
```

In my Trait method GetDataTable

```
public function scopeGetDataTable($query,$request)
{

    $query = $query->searching($request->search);

    if ($request->per_page == -1 ) {
        $perPage  =  $query->count();
    }else{
        $perPage  =$request->per_page;
    }

    if ($request->sortBy == 'null' ) {
        $ordercolumn ='id';
    }else{
        $ordercolumn =$request->sortBy;
    }
    $order =$request->order;
    $pos = strpos($ordercolumn, '.');
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $column = explode(".", $ordercolumn);
        return $query->with([$column[0] => function ($query)  use ($column,$order){ 
            $query->orderBy($column[1],$order ?? 'ASC');
        }])->paginate($perPage);
    }else{
        return  $query->orderBy($ordercolumn ?? 'id', $order ?? 'ASC')
                ->paginate($perPage);
    }
 }
```

in my models I have a scope

```
 public function scopeSearching($query, $que)
 {

        $columns = ['id','','',....];
        foreach($columns as $column){
            $query->orWhere($column, 'LIKE', "%$que%");
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please add the whole `GetDataTable()` method.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I already added it, with the scope that I also use, I hope it helps to understand better what I try

Comment: What does "it does not order correctly" mean?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir you should sort the records of the parent model, by the field of your relationship, if you send by request relation.name, you should sort the Model records according to the name of your relationship.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example with relationships, `$request` object and executed queries.

Comment: I'm not sure what youre trying to do but you might want to use something like https://packagist.org/packages/sofa/eloquence `composer require sofa/eloquence` which allows you to search more easily on all your models

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir The question would be very broad, I just want something global that works for any type of relationship

Comment: Eloquent has limited support for this. The query builder is a lot more flexibel. E.g. You can orderBy on the top level QueryBuilder object by prepending the tablename before the column name 'relation.id'.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
$results = \App\Country::join('currencies', 'currencies.id', '=', 'countries.currency_id')->orderBy('currencies.name')->get();
```

If you only want the country data withouth the currency data yo add a select to the query

```
$results = \App\Country::join('currencies', 'currencies.id', '=', 'countries.currency_id')->select('countries.*')->orderBy('currencies.name')->get();
```

This will get you all the countries that have currencies order by the currency name.

You have to change the model to your model and the relation to your relation.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but please check well, I am using eloquent and not query builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested relation ordering and relation existing query with Eloquent.

[Check Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Example:

```
$relation_sort = 'asc';
$nested_sort = 'desc';

$result = Model::with([
   'relation' => function($query) use($relation_sort){
      $query->orderBy('relation_column', $relation_sort);
   },
   'relation.nested' => function($query) use($nested_sort){
      $query->orderBy('nested_relation_column', $nested_sort);
   }
])->whereHas('relation', function($query){
    //Relation exists check.
    $query->where('price', '>', 100);

})->whereHas('relation.nested', function($query) use($search_param){
    //Nested Relation search.
    $query->where('search_column', 'LIKE', $search_param);
})->get();
```